# LineageOS kernel compile errors

Tags: android, build, compilation, kernel

I'm trying to compile the LineageOS kernel source for my device Galaxy S4 (jfltexx).

**Kernel:** https://github.com/LineageOS/android_device_samsung_jflte

**Toolchain:** https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/

**System:** `Xubuntu 17.10 (64 bit)` with `gcc 7.2.0` and `GNU Make 4.1`

In order to compile the kernel for my target, I'm using the build script from the kernel repository:

```
python build-all.py jf_eur
```

The compilation usually stops at one point and the log contains the following:

```
GEN     /home/computer/Desktop/output/all-kernels/jf_eur/Makefile
scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig
drivers/usb/otg/Kconfig:187:warning: leading whitespace ignored
drivers/media/video/msm-jf/Kconfig:114:warning: choice value used outside its choice group
drivers/media/video/msm/Kconfig:108:warning: choice value used outside its choice group
drivers/media/video/msm-jf/Kconfig:119:warning: choice value used outside its choice group
drivers/media/video/msm/Kconfig:113:warning: choice value used outside its choice group
  Using /home/computer/Desktop/Android/test as source for kernel
  GEN     /home/computer/Desktop/output/all-kernels/jf_eur/Makefile
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[2]: 'include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
  GEN     include/generated/bounds.h
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.s
  GEN     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  CALL    /home/computer/Desktop/Android/test/scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  HOSTCC  scripts/genksyms/genksyms.o
  SHIPPED scripts/genksyms/lex.lex.c
  SHIPPED scripts/genksyms/keywords.hash.c
  SHIPPED scripts/genksyms/parse.tab.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/genksyms/lex.lex.o
  SHIPPED scripts/genksyms/parse.tab.c
  HOSTCC  scripts/genksyms/parse.tab.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/genksyms/genksyms
  CC      scripts/mod/empty.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/mk_elfconfig
  MKELF   scripts/mod/elfconfig.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/file2alias.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/modpost.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/sumversion.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/mod/modpost
  HOSTCC  scripts/kallsyms
  HOSTCC  scripts/conmakehash
  HOSTCC  scripts/bin2c
  CC      init/main.o
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  UPD     include/generated/compile.h
  CC      init/version.o
  CC      init/do_mounts.o
  CC      init/do_mounts_rd.o
  CC      init/do_mounts_initrd.o
  LD      init/mounts.o
  CC      init/initramfs.o
  CC      init/calibrate.o
  LD      init/built-in.o
  HOSTCC  usr/gen_init_cpio
  GEN     usr/initramfs_data.cpio
  AS      usr/initramfs_data.o
  LD      usr/built-in.o
  CC      arch/arm/vfp/vfpmodule.o
  AS      arch/arm/vfp/entry.o
  AS      arch/arm/vfp/vfphw.o
  CC      arch/arm/vfp/vfpsingle.o
  CC      arch/arm/vfp/vfpdouble.o
  LD      arch/arm/vfp/vfp.o
  LD      arch/arm/vfp/built-in.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/elf.o
  AS      arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.o
  AS      arch/arm/kernel/entry-common.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/irq.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/opcodes.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/process.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/ptrace.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/return_address.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/sched_clock.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/setup.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/signal.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/stacktrace.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/time.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/traps.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/cpuidle.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/armksyms.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/module.o
  AS      arch/arm/kernel/sleep.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/suspend.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/smp.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/smp_tlb.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/smp_scu.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/unwind.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/swp_emulate.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/hw_breakpoint.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/update_vsyscall_arm.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/pmu.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/perf_event.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/topology.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/user_accessible_timer.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/io.o
  LD      arch/arm/kernel/built-in.o
  AS      arch/arm/kernel/head.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/init_task.o
  LDS     arch/arm/kernel/vmlinux.lds
  CC      arch/arm/mm/dma-mapping.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/extable.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/fault.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/init.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/iomap.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/fault-armv.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/flush.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/idmap.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/ioremap.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/mmap.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/pgd.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/mmu.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/vmregion.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/proc-syms.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/alignment.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/highmem.o
  AS      arch/arm/mm/abort-ev7.o
  AS      arch/arm/mm/pabort-v7.o
  AS      arch/arm/mm/cache-v7.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/copypage-v6.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/context.o
  AS      arch/arm/mm/tlb-v7.o
  AS      arch/arm/mm/proc-v7.o
  LD      arch/arm/mm/built-in.o
  CC      arch/arm/common/gic.o
  CC      arch/arm/common/cpaccess.o
  LD      arch/arm/common/built-in.o
  LD      arch/arm/net/built-in.o
  LD      arch/arm/crypto/built-in.o
  CC      arch/arm/mach-msm/io.o
  CC      arch/arm/mach-msm/dma.o
  CC      arch/arm/mach-msm/memory.o
  CC      arch/arm/mach-msm/timer.o
  CC      arch/arm/mach-msm/clock.o
  CC      arch/arm/mach-msm/clock-voter.o
  CC      arch/arm/mach-msm/clock-dummy.o
  CC      arch/arm/mach-msm/modem_notifier.o
  CC      arch/arm/mach-msm/subsystem_map.o
  CC      arch/arm/mach-msm/acpuclock.o
  CC      arch/arm/mach-msm/perf_trace_counters.o
/home/computer/Desktop/Android/test/arch/arm/mach-msm/perf_trace_counters.c: In function 'tracectr_cpu_hotplug_notifier':
/home/computer/Desktop/Android/test/arch/arm/mach-msm/perf_trace_counters.c:32:18: error: 'CPU_TASKS_FROZEN' undeclared (first use in this function)
  if ((action & (~CPU_TASKS_FROZEN)) == CPU_STARTING)
                  ^
/home/computer/Desktop/Android/test/arch/arm/mach-msm/perf_trace_counters.c:32:18: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/computer/Desktop/Android/test/arch/arm/mach-msm/perf_trace_counters.c:32:40: error: 'CPU_STARTING' undeclared (first use in this function)
  if ((action & (~CPU_TASKS_FROZEN)) == CPU_STARTING)
                                        ^
/home/computer/Desktop/Android/test/arch/arm/mach-msm/perf_trace_counters.c: In function 'init_tracecounters':
/home/computer/Desktop/Android/test/arch/arm/mach-msm/perf_trace_counters.c:173:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'register_cpu_notifier' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  register_cpu_notifier(&tracectr_cpu_hotplug_notifier_block);
  ^
/home/computer/Desktop/Android/test/arch/arm/mach-msm/perf_trace_counters.c: In function 'exit_tracecounters':
/home/computer/Desktop/Android/test/arch/arm/mach-msm/perf_trace_counters.c:181:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'unregister_cpu_notifier' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  unregister_cpu_notifier(&tracectr_cpu_hotplug_notifier_block);
  ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
/home/computer/Desktop/Android/test/scripts/Makefile.build:307: recipe for target 'arch/arm/mach-msm/perf_trace_counters.o' failed
make[2]: *** [arch/arm/mach-msm/perf_trace_counters.o] Error 1
/home/computer/Desktop/Android/test/Makefile:973: recipe for target 'arch/arm/mach-msm' failed
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/mach-msm] Error 2
Makefile:130: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make: *** [sub-make] Error 2
```

I have been searching the internet, but only found one topic where a user mentioned that 'tracing' caused them this error:

https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=53850620&postcount=32456

> I solved my problem reverting an old patch that disabled tracing, everything is up in my git

Since I'm using the latest kernel sources and the device is still actively supported with complete LineageOS builds, I thought the kernel should probably compile just fine. I also watched some Youtube videos where people compiled kernels the same way I am trying to.

Am I using a wrong toolchain or other programms?

I'm glad for any help, thanks!

Comment: can you mark the answer?